# Getting crash when try to delete row from UITableView when I have multiple sections. Section values are in Dynamic NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, delete-row

Let me describe what I actually want. I have a dictionary where keys are Alphabets and it's values are starting with that alphabet.

Something like this :

```
key     value
---------------------------------------------------------
A       (Apple, Aim, Arise, Attempt, Airplane, Absolute)
B       (Bubble, Bite, Borrow, Basket)
C       (Cat, Correct)
D       (Dog, Direction, Distribute)
```

My `NSMutableDictionary` call `wordDic` have all data Alphabetically. Just like the above table. I pull all data from my `ManagedObject` and show them in that dictionary.

```
- (void)dataStructure
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Words"];

    self.wordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.wordListArray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    self.wordInWordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordListArray count]; i++)
    {
        self.words = [self.wordListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.wordInWordListArray addObject:self.words.word];
    }

    if ([self.wordListArray count] != 0)
    {
        self.wordDic = [self sortedDictionary:self.wordInWordListArray];

        // Sorted key array
        self.keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *key = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        key = [self.wordDic allKeys];
        self.keyArray = [key sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }

    [self.homeTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self viewRelatedChange];
    [self dataStructure];
}
```

These data are showing in `tableView` perfectly. But when I try to delete a particular row, it got crash. The message is something like `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`, which means in my `numberOfRowsInSection`, tableView try to access a row, which is not exist. So I have to handle that according to my data structure. What I did is in `commitEditingStyle` after delete `object` from my `mangedObject` and my `tableView` array, I call the above method `[self dataStructure];`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *selectedString = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *words = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];
    [words sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Words" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like %@", [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            [context deleteObject:obj];
        }
        [context save:&error];

        // remove info from tableView array
        int coreDataIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordInWordListArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *dataString = [self.wordInWordListArray objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([dataString isEqualToString:selectedString])
            {
                coreDataIndex = i;
            }
        }

        [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:coreDataIndex];
        [words removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[self.homeTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[self.homeTableView endUpdates];
    }
    [self dataStructure];
}
```

But it is not working. And my apps still getting crash with same message. I also notice that in `numberOfRowsInSection` the value of `section` is not always start with 0. (like `indexPath.row` did). So what's the problem of my structure and what will be the solution of it?

Below I am giving the full code, of my `tableView`. If any one have an answer, please share that with me. It would be very appreciable. A lot of thanks in advance. Good day to all.

```
- (void)dataStructure
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Words"];

    self.wordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.wordListArray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    self.wordInWordListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordListArray count]; i++)
    {
        self.words = [self.wordListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.wordInWordListArray addObject:self.words.word];
    }

    if ([self.wordListArray count] != 0)
    {
        self.wordDic = [self sortedDictionary:self.wordInWordListArray];

        // Sorted key array
        self.keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *key = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        key = [self.wordDic allKeys];
        self.keyArray = [key sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }

    [self.homeTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self viewRelatedChange];
    [self dataStructure];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.keyArray count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 28;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"section %ld", (long)section);
    NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSMutableArray *value = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];

   // NSLog(@"keys %@", key);
    NSLog(@"values %@", value);

    return [value count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return kHomeTableViewExpandedCellHeight;
    } else {
        return kHomeTableViewCellHeight;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = kHomeTableViewCellID;
        HomeTableViewCell *cell = (HomeTableViewCell *)[self.homeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[HomeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        secData = [self.wordDic objectForKey:secTitle];
        [secData sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        NSString *data = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.wordLabel setText:data];

//        NSManagedObject *words = [self.wordListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        [cell.wordLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words valueForKey:@"word"]]];

        return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    NSString *secTitle = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *selectedString = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *words = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];
    [words sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Words" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like %@", [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            [context deleteObject:obj];
        }
        [context save:&error];

        // remove info from tableView array
        int coreDataIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordInWordListArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *dataString = [self.wordInWordListArray objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([dataString isEqualToString:selectedString])
            {
                coreDataIndex = i;
            }
        }

        [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:coreDataIndex];
        [words removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[self.homeTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[self.homeTableView endUpdates];
    }
    [self dataStructure];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try calling the dataStructure method before deleting the appropriate row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedString = [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *key = [self.keyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *words = [self.wordDic objectForKey:key];
    [words sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Words" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word like %@", [secData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            [context deleteObject:obj];
        }
        [context save:&error];

        // remove info from tableView array
        int coreDataIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.wordInWordListArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *dataString = [self.wordInWordListArray objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([dataString isEqualToString:selectedString])
            {
                coreDataIndex = i;
            }
        }

        [self.wordListArray removeObjectAtIndex:coreDataIndex];
        [words removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self dataStructure];

        //[self.homeTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.homeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        //[self.homeTableView endUpdates];
    }
```

}

`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` will basically reload the tableView which in turn calls `numberOfRowsInSection` method. So before control reaches `numberOfRowsInSection`, your data source should be updated

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did it. And still it is crashing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem. In `commitEditingStyle` when I was removing my tableView data I was used `secData` which is basically hold the selected `indexPath.row`. Instead of it, I have to use the

```
[words objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in `predicate`. It's now working perfectly. :)